# Compiling python in atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I use atom to compile my python code. I want to test my IDE.But I faced this problem.This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bad argument
internal/child_process.js:289
TypeError: Bad argument
at TypeError (native)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:289:26)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:392:9)
at compile (C:\Users\wenzh\.atom\packages\gpp-compiler\index.js:274:31)
at compileFile (C:\Users\wenzh\.atom\packages\gpp-compiler\index.js:216:5)
at atom-text-editor.gpp-compiler:compile (C:\Users\wenzh\.atom\packages\gpp-compiler\index.js:23:11)
at CommandRegistry.module.exports.CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (C:\Users\wenzh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\resources\app.asar\src\command-registry.js:259:29)
at C:\Users\wenzh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\resources\app.asar\src\command-registry.js:3:59
at KeymapManager.module.exports.KeymapManager.dispatchCommandEvent (C:\Users\wenzh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\atom-keymap\lib\keymap-manager.js:599:16)
at KeymapManager.module.exports.KeymapManager.handleKeyboardEvent (C:\Users\wenzh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\atom-keymap\lib\keymap-manager.js:390:22)
at WindowEventHandler.module.exports.WindowEventHandler.handleDocumentKeyEvent (C:\Users\wenzh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.15.0\resources\app.asar\src\window-event-handler.js:106:36)
```

At the last, the atom said:

```
The error was thrown from the gpp-compiler package. This issue has already been reported.
```

How do I solve it?Thanks!

Comment: it seams an open issue for atom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200319/compiling-python-in-atom, so, better to ask them directly (github)

Answer (score 0):

i just solved the problem. You can go to "File"-->"Keymap...", then will open the file "keymap.cson". you can add below at bottom. which means F7 for gpp complier, and F5 for python run:

```
'.editor:not(.mini)':
    "f7": "gpp-compiler:compile"
    "f5": "Python run: run-f5"
```